# How to show $\text{rref }[\left.A\right|AB]=[\left.I_n\right|B]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

For invertible $A^{n\times n}, B^{n\times n}$, how do I show that $\text{rref }[\left.A\right|AB]=[\left.I_n\right|B]?$

---

Tentatively: $\text{rref }[\left.A\right|AB]=[\left.I_n\right|ABA^{-1}],\text{where rref }[\left.A\right|I_n]=[\left.I_n\right|A^{-1}]\\\text{and }ABA^{-1}=AA^{-1}B=I_nB\\\Rightarrow\text{rref }[\left.A\right|AB]=[\left.I_n\right|ABA^{-1}]=[\left.I_n\right|I_nB]=[\left.B^{-1}\right|I_n^2]=[\left.B^{-1}\right|I_n]=[\left.I_n\right|B]\\\text{ where }\det A, \det B\neq0\ $

---

I'm not confident about the third line, specifically the difference between $\text{rref }[\left.A\right|AB]$ and $[\left.A\right|AB]$ with augmented matrices. Can I still move things around and take inverses without $\text{rref}$ on the left?

---

I'm given the following hint:

> "The left part of $\text{rref }[\left.A\right|AB]$ is $\text{rref }(A)=I_n$. Write $\text{rref }[\left.A\right|AB]=[I_n|M]$; we have to show that $M=B$. To demonstrate this, note that the columns of matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}B\\-I_n\end{bmatrix}$$are in the kernel of $[\left.A\right|AB]$ and therefore in the kernel of $[\left.I_n\right|M]$."

---

I didn't use the hint at all in formulating my proof, which raises doubts. Is the proof along the lines of  $$\begin{bmatrix}B\\-I_n\end{bmatrix}\in\text{ker }([\left.A\right|AB],\begin{bmatrix}B\\-I_n\end{bmatrix}\in\text{ker }([\left.I_n\right|B])\\\Rightarrow\text{ker }[\left.I_n\right|B]\subseteq\text{ker }([\left.A\right|AB]\\\Rightarrow\text{rref }[\left.A\right|AB]=[\left.I_n\right|B]\,?$$

Comment: Isn't $\text{rref}[A|AB]=\text{rref}[I_n|A^{-1}AB]=\text{rref}[I_n|B]$?

Comment: Maybe? I thought $\text{rref }[\left.A\right|AB]=[\left.I_n\right|B]\stackrel{?}{=}\text{rref }[\left.I_n\right|B]$

Comment: They should be the same, since they are $n\times n$ matrices. The left side $I_n$ gives you all the leading $1$'s.

Comment: I see what you mean. But isn't $\text{rref }[\left.I_n\right|B]=[\left.B^{-1}\right|I_n]$, where $\text{rref }[\left.B\right|I_n]=[\left.I_n\right|B^{-1}]?$ and $[\left.B^{-1}\right|I_n]=[\left.I_n\right|B^{-1}]\iff B=B^{-1}\nvDash\forall\,B^{n\times n}\,$?

Comment: $\text{rref }[\left.I_n\right|B]=[\left.B^{-1}\right|I_n]$ is not right. The rref of a rank $n$ matrix has to have $I_n$ on the left. $\text{rref }[\left.B\right|I_n]=[\left.I_n\right|B^{-1}]$ is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

**First proof:** Write $A$ as a product of Elementary matrices, and use the fact that if you make the corresponding row operation you cancel an elementary matrix from left.

**Second proof** Let $b_j$ be the $j$-th column of $B$. Then the $jth$ column of $AB$ is $Ab_j$.

Now, when you row reduce $[A|Ab_j]$ you are solving the system of equations 
$$Ax=Ab_j$$
since $A$ is invertible, it has unique solution, which implies that
$$rref[A|Ab_j] = [I_n|b_j]$$
for each $j$. Conclude from here that
$$ rref[A|Ab_1 Ab_2 ... Ab_k] = [I_n|b_1 b_2 ... b_k]=[I | B]$$

Comment: What do you mean by "elementary matrix"? the term is not defined in my textbook (Bretscher, 2013).

Comment: @BenjaminLoya Any row operation is equivalent to multiplication on the left by an invertible matrix. These matrices are called elementary matrices.

Answer (score 1):

suppose $[A|AB]$ is row equivalent to $[I|C].$ we are given 
$\begin{bmatrix}B\\-I\end{bmatrix}$ 
is in the null space of $[A|AB].$ therefore is in the null space of $[I|C].$ that implies  $B-C = 0$ that is $$C = B. $$

Comment: How do we show that $[\left.A\right|AB]$ is "row equivalent" to $[\left.I_n\right|C]?$ Can we define "row equivalent" more specifically? I haven't heard that terminology before - I assume it means that their kernels are identical?

Comment: @BenjaminLoya, row equivalence means you can one matrix from the other by multiplying on the left by nonsingular matrix, usually elementary row operations. the reason you get $A|B \to I|C$ is that $A$ is nonsingular.